# Algebraic data type (intended) name collision.. how to?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I had the idea to implement my own little music theory module in Haskell.

Starting with notes (`Note`) makes sense and right there and then I ran into this nasty syntactic problem, I have no idea how real Haskellers handle it.

```
data Note = Sharp NoteS | Flat NoteF deriving (Show)

data NoteS = 
    C | SC | D | SD | E | F | SF | G | SG | B
    deriving (Ord,Show,Eq)

data NoteF = 
    C | FD | D | FE | E | F | FG | G | FB | B
    deriving (Ord,Show,Eq)

instance Eq Note where
    (==) (NoteS n1) (NoteS n2) = n1 == n2
    (==) (NoteF n1) (NoteF n2) = n1 == n2
    (==) (NoteS n1) (NoteF n2) = ???
    (==) (NoteF n1) (NoteS n2) = ???
    ...

flatToSharp :: Note -> NoteS
sharpToFlat :: Note -> NoteF
```

As most might know, a sharp C and a flat D are synonymous in general but sometimes it is prefered to use one or the other depending on context. So I hoped to use the fact that both `NoteS` and `NoteF` are instances of `Ord` (e.g. for interval calculation). But in both representations, the plain notes (C,D,E,F...) have the same names in both types.

Now I could think of ways to "hack" around this syntactic problem. But it would either have ugly syntactic implications or run time implications (e.g. use Strings instead of a types, lots of testing and error checking,...).

So here is my question to Haskell professionals... How would I do it in the spirit of my idea without too many concessions to this "namespace" problem of Haskell?

I tried `{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}` but it does not help with unions, obviously.

Comment: As far as I can see, you don't need to have `NoteS` and `NoteF` as separate types. With something like `data Note = Sharp BaseNote | Flat BaseNote`, you would already be able to distinguish sharps and flats through the `Sharp` and `Flat` constructors while writing the `Eq` instance. (Note that there may well be a better encoding than the one I have just suggested.)

Comment: Indeed - for ``Eq`` this would work but then I would have to really calculate for intervals instead of just using ``Ord`` for intervals. My idea here is like ``NoteS D + 5`` to get the perfect fifth. Okay I would have to use halfsteps but for the sake of this question it should not matter.

Comment: You won't really be able to use `+`, as that's about the only operation from the `Num` typeclass that makes sense for `Notes`.

Comment: @chepner You are right! Maybe using ``Enum`` is more appropriate here.

Comment: I think I see what you want (to run through the chromatic scale using different picks of note names), and it does make sense, but I'm not sure achieving it in this way would be worth the trouble. The main thing that causes me some alarm is having three separate note types with no clear indication of which is the canonical representation of notes in your model. Besides making the model harder to understand, that could easily lead to a tangle of conversion functions all around, which might be more annoying to deal with than the upfront investment in writing some extra code for the instances.

Comment: I don't think it makes much musical sense to use separate constructors for sharps, flats (and naturals). These are all just notes on a twelve-tone scale.

Comment: In the end I went with @duplode 's first idea + implementing ``Enum`` first. With that, ``Eq`` instance is a 3 liner and I can type in ghci: ``take 12 [(Natural C),(Natural G)..]`` and voilà - I have the circle of fifths: ``[Natural C,Natural G,Natural D,Natural A,Natural E,Natural B,Sharp F,Sharp C,Sharp G,Sharp D,Sharp A,Natural F]`` Isn't that pretty? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you must keep the data representation as you have it there, the standard namespacing mechanism in Haskell is modules. So you could write

```
module Sharps where data NoteS = ...

module Flats where data NoteF = ...

module Main where
import Sharps as S
import Flats as F
```

(Of course, don't forget that for GHC, each module must go in its own file with an appropriate filename.) Then, in `Main`, you could refer to `Sharps.C` or `S.C` to get the `NoteS` constructor, and `Flats.C` or `F.C` to get the `NoteF` constructor.

But may I propose a different solution? How about naming the natural notes, and simply having a type that records how sharp or flat you've gone from there? After all, you're going to want to handle double sharps and double flats eventually, I'm sure. So:

```
data Natural = A | B | C | D | E | F | G
data Note = Note
    { natural :: Natural
    , offset :: Int -- positive for sharp, negative for flat, say
    }
```

(There are many other data representation choices you could make as well.)

Comment: `offset` is nice because double sharps flats do occur, on occasion.

Answer (score 5):

Another idea is to use a pattern synonym. You can have a single type representing notes, and synonyms to rename some of them.

https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#pattern-synonyms

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonym #-}

data Note = C | SC | D | SD | E | F | SF | G | SG | B

pattern FD = SC
pattern FE = SD
pattern FG = SF
pattern FB = SG
```

Comment: Nice. Plus this lets you reuse the derived instances for a bunch of stuff (`Eq`, `Ord`, `Bounded`, `Enum` all come nice and clean). However, if you ever want to display notes to musicians (as opposed to other machines) you do sometimes want to distinguish between the sharp and flat versions; e.g. a musician would holler if your pretty-printed F major scale was `F G A A# C...` instead of `F G A Bb C...`.